# How to enable TLS on OpenLDAP when Replication already running

Tags: ssl, ldap, replication

I set up a replication between two hosts by following [this](http://www.cyrill-gremaud.ch/linux/howto-setup-n-way-multi-master-replication-with-openldap/) great manual. The replication is running fine - already since a couple of months.

Now I want to enable TLS, too (replication does not need to have TLS).

Since the host has Ubuntu Linux, I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-tls) guide to create a self signed SSL certificate and am now stuck on the step to modify the server configuration. This is my LDIF file:

```
$ cat tls.ldif 
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap_slapd_cacert.pem

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap_slapd_key.pem

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap_slapd_cert.pem
```

And the command to import fails:

```
$ ldapmodify  -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -f ~/tls.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
```

Using a combination of IP address, TCP port and credentials does not do anything different.

OLC Mirror Mode is on:

```
$ slapcat -n 0
[ -cut- ]
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by     
 dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: c7822d8e-30c4-1037-8e8b-4fac89b22db9
createTimestamp: 20170918135531Z
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config
refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
[ -cut- ]
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping back to the beginning, erasing the files for certificates, keys and infos, then everything new.

It worked.

Obviously, I did something wrong before. Although the SSL certificates and keys looked ok, they were not. And, even more surprising: Inserting the three values is more than a stupid insertion of values, they are obviously validated upon setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your LDIF file to look like this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap_slapd_cacert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap_slapd_key.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap_slapd_cert.pem
```

This should mean your three additions are seen as one change rather than three separate ones. OpenLDAP is probably being picky because it's only seeing each change in isolation.

Comment: nope, same error.